# Where are the default packages in Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm migrating from Sublime Text 2 to 3. In Sublime Text 2, I changed a lot of the default settings of the editor -- such as the tab bar height, sidebar color, etc. -- by modifying the `Default.sublime-theme` file in `sublime-text-2/Packages/Theme - Default`. I was also able to modify the colors of the default color schemes in a similar fashion. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for Sublime Text 3, but can't seem to find these files. `~/.config/sublime-text-3` only seems to contain overrides for user settings, not the default settings.

[This link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10933) on the Sublime Text forums seems to give the location for Windows and Mac, but not for Ubuntu. I've searched a bit to no avail. Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To amplify on @skuroda's answer - ST3 contains all of its data that, in ST2, was stored in `Packages/PackageName`, in `PackageName.sublime-package` files that are basically just zip files, or "Resources" as they're now known. Using `PackageResourceViewer`, you can easily edit the individual files contained within the resource, then save it back again. When saved, the proper directory structure under `Packages/PackageName` will be created, allowing you to edit the file directly next time. The way file precedence works in Sublime, any file that exists in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/PackageName/` will override any file of the same name stored in `PackageName.sublime-package`.

However, since you don't want these files to be accidentally overwritten, I would suggest creating `~/config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Themes/` and `User/Color Schemes` directories and storing your customized files there instead. The `User/` directory is protected from overwrites during upgrades, etc., and unless you're planning on creating a customized theme or color scheme for redistribution through Package Control, it's best practice to keep your files in there.

---

#### ***EDIT***

I just realized you hadn't gotten an answer to your original question - where are the files stored? If you installed the `.deb` file from sublimetext.com, all the `.sublime-package` files are in `/opt/sublime_text/Packages`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation about the best practice and showing me how to do what I'm _actually_ trying to do, rather than what I (incorrectly) asked in my question :)

Comment: Though I could be wrong, I believe overriding package files are also protected. Well, from the editor doing anything to them on upgrades. That being said, I'd still recommend placing items in the User directory as MattDMo described. It makes moving between machines much easier :)

Comment: The problem with storing in `Packages/User` versus `Packages/PackageName` it that it does not override the default files for all file types.  I tried this with a `.sublime-build` file and it I end up with double the build options and the default with Ctrl+B is not my own.

Answer (score 13):

If you want the easiest way to save your customized settings first copy all the default settings and paste into a new file named  `Preferences.sublime-settings`.

Then make your changes and save the file to:

```
/home/**username**/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User
```

In order to see the `.config` folder you will have to enable `show hidden files`.

The instructions are written at the top of the default settings list in case you are wondering where got this from.

Answer (score 8):

In the ST console, try entering `sublime.executable_path()`. This should get you close to where you need to be. Also, you should copy the content of the file out and move them (under a new name to the packages folder). You probably don't want your modifications to be reverted on subsequent update. An alternative method is to try overriding the files you need to. I haven't done that for theme files, so I'm unsure if everything will work as it should. If you take the override route, I'd recommend using [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). I wrote it to help with browsing/overriding package files in ST3.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and useful reference to the PackageResourceViewer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

For example

```
dpkg -L subli<tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open up sublime text, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to open sublime text console, then run these command accordingly

- `sublime.packages_path()` to see user installed packages directory
- `sublime.installed_packages_path()` to see zipped packages (with `.sublime-package` file type) directory

Mostly likely, you'll find the `Default` package inside zipped packages directory.

You can use [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to see zipped packages's contents as @MattDMo suggested, but more over, you can actually extract zipped packages into user installed package directory directly using `PackageResourceViewer`'s extract command.